# Android: disabled View gets focus

Tags: android, view, checkbox, radio-button, android-edittext

I don't know exactly how to search about this topic, so I hope there isn't the same question here around.

In a "menu" of my `Activity`, I have two `RadioButtons` with EditText's, the user should choose one of the two options and then enter some values in the `EditText`. The first `RadioButton`, however, has an additional Option which is choosable via a `CheckBox`, so that if the user checks that `CheckBox`, a further `EditText` is enabled. The `EditText`'s are dis- and enabled via onCheckedChangeListener on both `RadioButtons` and the `CheckBox` like this

```
radio1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked){
                    if(radio2.isChecked()){
                        radio2.setChecked(false);
                    }
                    edit1.setEnabled(true);
                    check1.setEnabled(true);
                }else{
                    check1.setEnabled(false);
                    check1.setChecked(false);
                }   
            }
        });
```

Now the problem is, when I choose option one, and enter a value in the first `EditText`, and the second one is still disabled, I can press the "forward-button" (I really don't know how it's called, see the image below) and the disabled `EditText` gets focused.

[image]

And here's the `EditText` that shouldn't be focused

[image]

Shouldn't it be that a disabled `View` could not get foucsed? It is absolutely illogical that this is even possible. Is there a way to set this generally or have I add `setFocusable(boolean)` every time I change the status?

Comment: Could you be clear and elaborate your code? editText.setEnabled(false) does disable the edittext and doesn't make the editText highlighted too. There must be somewhere wrong in your code. BTW where are you disabling your edittext initially?

Comment: If you would read carefully, you'd see that I already wrote: the EditText gets highlighted by pressing the button on the android keyboard (red circle on the first image). And further it doesn't matter where I initially disable the Views, it's about the principle that they initially ARE disabled and CAN BE focused, what in my oppinion is unlogical.

Answer (score 2):

The editTexts even though setEnabled as false can still receive focus. To disable the focus apply editText.setFocusable(false). On applying this on clicking the imeOption on the softkeyboard will then hide the softkeyboard if no other editable elements are present.